# How find BlockDecl nodes in Clang AST using AST Matcher?

Tags: clang, abstract-syntax-tree, clang-ast-matchers

I need to find self references in blocks (Objective C). And I'm using Clang AST Matchers for this.

The matcher to find all self references I've created is below:

```
declRefExpr(to(varDecl(hasName("self")))
```

Now I need to apply this matcher for blocks only. But I can't find how to do it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I would have expected to write something like `declRefExpr( hasAncestor(blockDecl()), etc)`, except there seems to be no blockDecl matcher. Maybe submit a feature request? I don't see how else to check for a block node.

Comment: I haven't find matcher for `BlockDecl` too, therefore I created `BlockExpr` matcher. But I found some cases when self is valid in block and it seems I need `BlockDecl` matcher again (see my answer below here).

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved the question by the following matcher (in OCLint):

```
virtual void setUpMatcher() override
{
    StatementMatcher blockExpression = expr(hasType(blockPointerType()));

    addMatcher(declRefExpr(to(varDecl(hasName("self"))), hasAncestor(blockExpression)).bind("selfRefInBlock"));

}
```

Ultimately I resolved to find `BlockExpr` instead of `BlockDecl`. So, the rule above finds self references in all block expressions.
But I didn't realize that in some blocks `self` is valid. For example the block within `dispatch_once` which executes a block object once and only once for the lifetime of an application.

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[self alloc] init];
    });
```

Therefore I think I need to find `BlockDecl` again :)